# Making a shape using drawable

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

When you build an Android app project, there is a background color preset file like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#ffffff"
      android:centerColor="#00ffff"
      android:endColor="#000000"
      android:type="linear"
      android:angle="90"/>
```

Using the string value of android:startColor, android:centerColor, android:endColor, android:type, android:angle, how can we make this gradient programmatically?

Comment: see `GradientDrawable`

Comment: There are gradientdrawable guides but they do not base on string values

Comment: what string values? what do you mean? did you check `GradientDrawable` documentation?

Comment: like "#000000"# not 0f-a0-c1..

Comment: Those are not strings. They are colors. You can use color resources to store them.

Comment: did you check `GradientDrawable` documentation? see `"Public constructors"` section

Comment: Oh, I think I can solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspire from this code, I think, that you'll get the main idea:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{startColor, endColor});
drawable.setStroke(strokeIntLength, strokeColor);

GradientDrawable drawableSelected = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{startColorDark, endColorDark});
drawableSelected.setStroke(strokeIntLength, strokeColorDark);

StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, drawable);
states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, drawableSelected);
states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, drawableSelected);
states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, drawableSelected);
states.addState(new int[]{}, drawable);

button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
```